# Open PDF in separate tab/window

Tags: asp.net, html, internet-explorer

I'm using the following code to display a PDF document in IE:

```
<a class="menu" href="file://MyServer/MyFolder/MyFile.pdf">Click Me!</a>
```

This displays the PDF in the current tab... how can I make this open in either a new tab or, preferably, a new window?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how you display in a new window:

```
  <a class="menu" href="file://MyServer/MyFolder/MyFile.pdf" target="_blank">Click Me!</a>
```

The target property can open any link (not just html or pdf) in other or the same window. Read about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink.target.aspx).

```
     _blank  Renders the content in a new window without frames.
     _parent Renders the content in the immediate frameset parent.
     _search Renders the content in the search pane.
     _self   Renders the content in the frame with focus.
     _top    Renders the content in the full window without frames.
```

Answer (score 4):

Add the "target" attribute to your A tag. For example:

```
<a class="menu" target="_blank" href="file://MyServer/MyFolder/MyFile.pdf">Click Me!</a>
```